# Rounding for loop

Tags: python

I have a bunch of values I need to round and convert to a string.  I think the best way to do so is to put them all in a list and then run the list through a for loop.  Here is an MRE but it does not work.

```
x = 2344.4444
y = 3666.3456
z = 89999.3224

LIST = [x,y,z]

for value in LIST:
   value = round(value, 1)
   value = "{:,}".format(value)
   value = str(value)

print(x)
```

The output is not reformatted.

Comment: You did not change `LIST`, that's why it looks the same as before.

Comment: This is not a [mcve] because you haven't said what the expected output or actual output is. The code you showed actually has no output.

Comment: You can't edit `value` in the loop. Reassigning it has no effect on the `LIST`. Use `enumerate` to get the index, then edit `LIST[index] `.

Comment: just put the new values in an other list

Comment: Sorry I'm using a jupyter notebook I edited so it prints LIST now

Comment: You place your rounded values into `value`, which you keep overwriting.  At the end, you print `x`, which you never changed.  You need to go back to your educational materials and learn how variables work.  Crunch through a few examples.  Learn to trace your code with intermediate `print` statements, so  you can follow your own logic, and see where it breaks down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a new list rather than modifying the one you already have.  The most concise way to do this in Python is using a list comprehension.  Here's an example that does what you're trying to do using the main logic you provide:

```
x = 2344.4444
y = 3666.3456
z = 89999.3224

my_list = [x,y,z]

my_new_list = ["{:,}".format(round(value, 1)) for value in my_list]

print(my_new_list)
```

Result:

```
['2,344.4', '3,666.3', '89,999.3']
```

Notice that I left out the call to `str()`.  That call is redundant.  The `format` method on a string object returns a string value.  Calling `str()` on that value does nothing to the value.

Notice that I changed the name of your input list from `LIST` to `my_list`.  Names in all caps are generally understood to be literal constants, and class names should always start with uppercase letters.  Variable names should generally start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thank very much.  How would I also convert to a string here?  In a separate line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking what happened to the call to `str()`?  I just added a note to the bottom of my answer explaining that.  If you're asking something else, please try to let me know just what it is that you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Use enumerate to get the index and the value for that index. Change value to string, then save to the index.

Here is the code:

```
x = 2344.4444
y = 3666.3456
z = 89999.3224

list1 = [x,y,z]
list2 = []

for index, value in enumerate(list1):
    value = round(value, 1)
    value = "{:,}".format(value)
    list2.append(value)

x,y,z = list2

print(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Thank you.  How would I do it if I wanted to be able to print any of the values in the new list later?  Say I wanted to print x and have it be rounded.  I edited my question to show more what I am going for....I apologize for the late edit.

Comment: I updated my answer. To print the value of x you would need to know its index in the list.

Comment: So I won't be able to print x by just referencing it without the list?  I don't want my code to be to confusing.  In reality I have about 25 variables I'm trying to round and be able to reference.

Comment: I updated my answer. Tell me if this is what you meant.